# Can boost::split Be Used on a List of Only One Token?

Tags: c++, algorithm, parsing, boost, boost-tokenizer

I would like to iterate over a comma-separated list of strings and do things with each string. Is there a way to set boost::split to recognize both "abc,xyz" and "abc" as valid inputs? In other words, can Split return the entire input string if it the predicate doesn't match anything?

Or should I be using boost:tokenizer instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost 1.54 does exactly what you want. Haven't tried newer versions.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

int main()
{
  std::string test1 = "abc,xyz";
  std::vector<std::string> result1;
  boost::algorithm::split(result1, test1, boost::is_any_of(","));
  for (auto const & s : result1)
  {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
  }

  std::string test2 = "abc";
  std::vector<std::string> result2;
  boost::algorithm::split(result2, test2, boost::is_any_of(","));
  for (auto const & s : result2)
  {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
abc
xyz
abc
```

Comment: Turns out the problem was never with Boost - the error I was getting was coming from a completely different place, it just looked like a Boost parsing error. Your response is, of course, completely correct.